# Polynomially decreasing lower bound for certain function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given $\delta>0$, consider the function $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb |z| \ge 1} \left(1 - \cos(\xi \cdot z)\right) |z|^{-n-\delta} \ dz $$ 
Can I find a function of $\xi$ of the form $|\xi|^{-\alpha}$, where $\alpha>0$? I failed to take a proper lower bound for $1-\cos(\xi \cdot z)$ and completely stucked :(

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_n(R)$ the integral of $1$ over the set $\{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2=R^2\}$. [It is well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere) that
$$ A_n(R) = R^{n-1}\cdot\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}.$$
By applying the shell method to our integral we have

$$ I = \int_{|z|>1}(1-\cos(\xi z))|z|^{-n-\delta}\,d\mu = \int_{1}^{+\infty}S_n(R)(1-\cos(\xi R))R^{-n-\delta}\,dR$$
hence:
$$ I = \frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\color{blue}{\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(\xi R)}{R^{1+\delta}}\,dR}$$
and the blue integral is easy to manage through integration by parts:
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(\xi R)}{R^{1+\delta}}\,dR=\frac{\cos(\xi)-1}{\delta}+\frac{\xi}{\delta}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\xi R)}{R^\delta}dR. $$